# What is the use of content:" ";?

Tags: html, css, opacity

What is the use of content: "" in this code?

I am trying to make my background image transparent in css3 , using opacity. There is no direct way but this gets the job done. However i do not understand the use of content here.

```
body::after{
    content: "";
    background: url(image.jpg); 
    opacity: 0.4; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [Pseudo-Element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html).

If you added `content: "123";` it would add that content into the page.  If you left out `content: "";` it would revert to default `content: none;` (actually default is normal which translates to none for content) which would mean there is nothing to style and everything else would be ignored.

Here is [more info on generated content](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content).